# Chinese Remainder theorem, no inverse?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$
\begin{cases}
x\equiv 7&\pmod{9} \\
x\equiv4 &\pmod{12} \\
x\equiv16&\pmod{21}
\end{cases}
$$

Compute $m$, $9*12*21=2268$.

Compute $M_1=$$m\over3$$=252$.

Compute $M_2=189$.

Compute $M_3=108$.

Here's where i'm struggling. The next step is to get the inverse of $252 \pmod9$, but when I apply euclid's algorithm I come up with a $\gcd \neq 1$, which to my understanding means there is no inverse.

How do i proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the first two equations simultaneously, you get x = 16(mod 108). Solving this result with the third equation simultaneously, you get x = 16(mod 2268) which reduces to x = 16(mod 252) because the combined modulus is the LCM.

Answer (score 1):

The combined modulus isn't their *product*: it's their *least common multiple*.

A simple approach would go the other way first: first break apart each modulus into its primary decomposition (e.g. $18 = 2 * 9$). Then you can combine all of the relatively prime moduli in the usual way.